# Store string time in sql.Time through spring @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I need to store time (hours and minutes) in backend. The data comes from UI in json and have the following view "10:00" as expamle. In backend I decided to keep this time in `sql.Time` type. The time comes to class through spring `@RequestBody` and consiquntly lead to exception: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Instantiation of [simple type, class java.sql.Time] value failed: null (through reference chain: biz.models.CarWash["firstShift"]);`

How to put my time in sql.Time field through `@RequestBody` annotation? 
And are that good ideas to keep time in `sql.Time` type and send it from UI in json as "10:00" ?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carwash/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Long addCarWashPUT(@RequestBody CarWash carWash) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(carWash);
    return 999L;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in that Jackson (by default used in Spring MVC) doesn't know how to transform "10:00" -> java.sql.Time, it is not obvious. You can define custom deserializer to do the transformation from string to java object:

```
public final class SqlTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<java.sql.Time> {

    @Override
    public java.sql.Time deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        String time = node.textValue();
        return // convert java.sql.Time from string
    }

....

}
```

To use this deserializer just put

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SqlTimeDeserializer.class)
```

above firstShift field in class CarWash

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the UI to send a JSON in this format:

```
{
    "firstShift": {
        "hours": 10,
        "minutes": 0
    }
}
```

You're fine with your controller.

An easy hack to know what kind of JSON needs to be passed would be just seeing how Spring formats your JSON (using Jackson Mapper):

```
@ResponseBody
public CarWash carWashJson() {
    CarWash cw = new CarWash();
    cw.setFirstShift(new Time(10, 0, 0));
    // Set other variables
    return cw;
}
```

And hit that controller to look at the produced JSON structure.

Comment: Can you explaim more precisely. Do you recommended to make in class 2 additional fields (hours and minutes) and then convers these 2 filed in `sql.Time` before save in DB ?

Comment: @RequestBody in Spring is usually sending a POST command to your REST end point with a JSON in the body.

I edited my answer with a sample controller.

Comment: Do you want to say that Spring combine hours and minutes parametes and set it somehow in one field `theTime` ? NB: I added my controller in the question tab